# What would you see standing on black hole just above the event horizon ? Will you look through past and future of the universe?

Tags: black-holes, reference-frames, time-dilation, event-horizon, time-travel

I am trying to imagine view from my house window if it was built on the black hole;) .... Of course I am joking.

If time near event horizon slows down with respect to rest of the universe. I could imagine time running faster for rest of the universe which would result in we viewing fast forward expansion of the universe till it tears apart completely. On the other hand we may also view slowed down light imprinted on the event horizon representing the past events of the universe.

I am not sure if I am right. Can someone please help me imagine the view standing on the event horizon of the black hole?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Practical time travel: time dilation above the event horizon](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/238343/)

Comment: This is used as a plot device in the [Heechee Saga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heechee) series by Frederick Pohl; a good read!