# What happens to electromagnetic field when crossing event horizon

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, black-holes, event-horizon

It is somewhat vague question. I have BSc in physics and  took a general relativity course some years ago. But this issue was never clear to me -  I am not looking for a formal explanation but just an outline of what the answer to my question might look like.

And here is the question:  I occasionally hear people referring to a thought experiment where someone falls into a black hole, usually accompanied by the assumption that black hole is large enough so that the tidal forces are not strong at the horizon. What I do not understand is what, say, happens with the electromagnetic field in a situation where one part of the body is already crossed into the horizon while the other part is still outside. Seems that the outside part has no way to interact with the inside part (except gravity) does this imply that the material disintegrates in some sense? Regardless of the tidal forces?

Comment: Nothing dramatic occurs , if the hole is big enough.  OK you are a goner, as in you can't get out, or send a signal out, but you can be blissfully innocent of this if the gravity gradient is mild. A smaller hole implies a steeper gradient which can pull you apart. Tidal forces are very mild on a large scale as far as I know. From your pov, things are fine.

Comment: But how does the part of my body ouside of horizon knows that it is attached to something which is already inside the horizon? Will my brain "feel" my legs which are already inside?

Comment: I don't think a large hole will be that extreme, I know you are implying how will your brain feel if you wave your feet, but there is not an abrupt cut off. Here is a more expert view http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/38123/what-do-you-feel-when-crossing-the-event-horizon?rq=1.  You have two pov, yours in which all is OK,  and one further away, where they will see you for a long, long time

Comment: Duplicate of.    http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/38123/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do you feel when crossing the event horizon?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/38123/)